# Make Master View Controller on iPad portrait behave exactly like iphone portrait

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, delegates, uisplitviewcontroller

So my problem is basically this:

I need to make master view controller visible fullscreen when ipad is in portrait mode (it would work the same as iphone). This is only for ipad portrait, for landscape my app should behave normally as it does on ipad.

I've tried changing `UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode` with no success (the only result i get is having master displayed along with detail, i would like to see master view only on ipad portrait)

I've also tried subclassing `UISplitViewController`, making it a delegate of `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` and using this method:

> splitViewController(_:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController:)

However the method never gets called...

```
class SplitVC: UISplitViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    delegate = self

}

// MARK: - UISplitViewControllerDelegate

func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    /// tried returning true here, but no effect too :(
    return false
}


func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    return nil

}

}
```

Any ideas why the delegate isnt called (I've even tried to put the delegate in appdelegate and still not called..) OR maybe there is some other solution to achieve the effect of master view controller being fullscreen on ipad in portrait mode ?